# CPU utilization degraded after upgrading java version from 1.7 to 1.8

Tags: java, java-8, cpu-usage, permgen, metaspace

For my application we have recently upgraded to java **1.8** from 1.7 and as per the performance test results we checked that CPU utilization is a big issue and it has increased by **71%** !!

**I'm using this below jvm arguments with jdk8:**

```
    -XX:-OptimizeStringConcat -XX:SurvivorRatio=6 -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:-UseGCOverheadLimit
```

Apart from all these the most import thing which I'm very confused is what is the MaxMetaSpaceSize we should choose now .

**For Jdk1.7 I was using :**

```
    -Xms480M -Xmx480M -XX:MaxPermSize=192M
```

**Kept everything same in jdk1.8 only changed the MaxPermSize to MaxMetaSpaceSize :**

```
    -Xms480M -Xmx480M -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=192M
```

Please let me know how can I improve the performance of my application . is there anything that I'm missing  - since jdk8 is using native memory area , therefore

1. inceasing the space on the server help or not .
2. I kept the value of MaxMetaspaceSize same as that of earlier - how can i decide on this value on this new architecture.

Comment: Why are you setting MaxMetaspaceSize? Metaspace isn't the same as PermGen anyway so I very much doubt you want the same value. Do you know what the JVM is doing with all that CPU? Have you got a thread dump?

Comment: thanks @sisyphus for helping out -

Earlier we were using "MaxPermSize"  , therefore after upgrading it to 1.8 , i thought will use "MaxMetaspaceSize" . but yes you are correct , both are not the same . We have got heap dumps from performance testing - is thread dump same as that of heap dump ?

Comment: They're not the same, no. A heap dump will tell you what's in memory, and a thread dump will tell you what threads were active. Both would be useful. However, if you've got a problem with CPU usage it's probably best to start with a thread dump.

Comment: With a 480M heap you don't need G1

Comment: It would also be worth investigating any GC logging you might have - G1 can have a slightly higher CPU usage, from my experience, and you may have your options set in a way which makes it quite sub-optimal.

Comment: Remove all GC options and see how it performs.

Comment: Get a trial of yourkit profiler and run it with your program